# sync password hashes of users UID>1000 between host A and B

Tags: users, perl

I have two CentOS systems, I want to do syncing of password hashes (only) which are stored in `/etc/shadow`, from system A (local) to system B (remote) but only for these users which have UID > 1000 and exist on both systems (basing on username, not UID which can vary for the same username on A an B).

I can't use rsync or solutions like LDAP or NIS. I also can't touch any accounts with UID < 1000 on these systems.

As UID of a user can differ on host A and B - to sync password hash from A to B following is important:
(1) the username must exist on both systems
(2) the username's UID must be >1000 (can differ) on both A and B systems

I have found a nice perl script of [Renaud Bompuis](https://serverfault.com/questions/18444/simple-one-way-synchronisation-of-user-password-list-between-servers/18461) which probably would need some adjustements to my requirements, it should not modify `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`. I am not a Perl programmer so I am looking for help here. Thank you in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Net::SCP qw(scp);
use strict;

use constant TRUE  => (1==1);
use constant FALSE => (1==0);

#--------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration
# Modify as needed
#--------------------------------------------------------
my $remoteHost = '10.13.113.2';  # email backup server
my $minUID     = 500;
my $maxUID     = 30000;
my $minGID     = 500;
my $maxGID     = 30000;

#--------------------------------------------------------
# Internal variables, normally not to be modified.
#--------------------------------------------------------
my $systemConfigDir = '/etc';
my $tmpDir = $ENV{TMPDIR} || $ENV{TMP} || $ENV{TEMP} || '/tmp';

#--------------------------------------------------------
#  Main
#--------------------------------------------------------
# STEP 1
# Get the remote files to /tmp and
# clean them of their normal users
ProcessFiles('remote');

# STEP 2
# Append the local normal users to the temp files
# and then send them back to the remote
ProcessFiles('local');

#--------------------------------------------------------
# ProcessFiles sub does one of two things:
# - if the passed argument is 'remote', then fetch each
#   user account file from the remote server, then remove
#   all normal users from each file, only keeping the
#   system users.
# - if the passed argument is 'local', then appends all
#   normal local users to the previously fetched and
#   cleaned-up files, then copies them back to the remote.
#--------------------------------------------------------
sub ProcessFiles {
        my $which = shift;
        my $tmpfile;
        my %username = ();
        my %usergroup = ();
        my %userUID = ();
        my %userGID = ();
        my @info;
        foreach my $f ('passwd','group','shadow','gshadow') {
                my $tmpfile = "$tmpDir/$f.REMOTE";
                if ($which eq 'remote') {
                        # Fetch the remote file
                        unlink $tmpfile if -e $tmpfile;
                        scp("$remoteHost:$systemConfigDir/$f", $tmpfile)
                                or die ("Could not get '$f' from '$remoteHost'");
                }
                # Glob the file content
                open CONFIGFILE, (($which eq 'remote') ? $tmpfile : "$systemConfigDir/$f");
                my @lines = <CONFIGFILE>;
                close CONFIGFILE;
                # Open the temp file, either truncating it or in append mode
                open TMPFILE,  (($which eq 'remote') ? ">$tmpfile" : ">>$tmpfile" )
                        or die "Could not open '$tmpfile' for processing";
                foreach my $line (@lines) {
                         # Skip comments, although they should be illegal in these files
                        next if $f =~ /^\s*#/;
                        @info = (split ':', $line);
                        if ($f eq 'passwd') {
                                my $uid = $info[2];
                                my $isnormaluser = ($uid > $minUID) && ($uid < $maxUID);
                                next if (($which eq 'remote') ? $isnormaluser : !$isnormaluser);
                                $username{$info[0]} = TRUE;
                                $userUID{$uid} = TRUE;
                                $userGID{$info[3]} = TRUE;
                        } elsif ($f eq 'group') {
                                my $gid = $info[2];
                                my $isnormalgroup = ($gid > $minGID) && ($gid < $maxGID);
                                next if (($which eq 'remote') ? $isnormalgroup : !$isnormalgroup);
                                $usergroup{$info[0]} = TRUE;
                        } elsif ($f eq 'shadow') {
                                next if !exists $username{$info[0]};
                        } else {
                                next if !exists $usergroup{$info[0]};
                        }
                        # Any line that reaches this point is valid
                        print TMPFILE $line;
                }
                close TMPFILE;
                if ($which eq 'local') {
                        # send the file back
                        scp($tmpfile, "$remoteHost:$systemConfigDir/$f") or
                                die ("Could not send '$f' to '$remoteHost'");
                        unlink $tmpfile;
                }
        }
}

#--------------------------------------------------------
# Make sure we cleanup the temp files when we exit
#--------------------------------------------------------
END {
        my $tmpfile;
        foreach my $f ('passwd','group','shadow','gshadow') {
                $tmpfile = "$tmpDir/$f.REMOTE";
                unlink $tmpfile if -e $tmpfile;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see necessity to copy a user password from system A to B if the user does not exist on B. Of course when such a user is one day created on system B, then his password should be synced from A to B.

Comment: You refer to UID<1000 and UID>1000. What about UID=1000?

Answer (score 1):

This will synchronise the entries in `/etc/shadow` from the local system to the remote system (here called `remotehost`) for all user accounts with UID > 1000 that exist on both systems:

```
getent passwd |
    awk -F: '$3>1000 {print $1}' |
    sort |
    join -t : -j 1 -o 2.{1..9} - <(getent shadow | sort) |
    ssh remotehost '
        cp -fp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow.old &&
        join -t : -j 1 -o 1.{1..9} - <(getent shadow | sort) |
            awk -F: "!h[\$1]++" - /etc/shadow >/etc/shadow.new &&
        : cp -f /etc/shadow.new /etc/shadow
    '
```

I strongly recommend that you split the command into pieces to see what it's doing at each stage of the pipeline, and that you DO NOT remove the no-op colon from the `: cp` on the last line until you are confident that it is working as you expect.

Essentially

1. Extract a list of usernames from `/etc/passwd` with UID > 1000
2. Use this list to extract the corresponding lines from `/etc/shadow`
3. Copy across to the remote system
4. Write out members of the new `shadow` list that exist in the current `/etc/shadow`
5. Write out lines from the old `/etc/shadow` whose usernames have not already been output
6. Save the original and new copies of `shadow` (in known places, for emergency rescue if needed)
7. Install the resulting merged file as `/etc/shadow`

Comment: +1.  BTW, instead of using `join`, `awk`, `sort`, and `cat` on the remote host, you could extract the `username:password` pairs on the local machine and pipe them to `chpasswd -e` on the remote host.   `chpasswd` will complain about unknown users (actually, PAM does the complaining), but still changes the usernames that exist.  Optionally redirect stderr to /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @roaiama's use of the `join` command, this answer uses `getent` to get the passwd and shadow files rather than reading them directly, and then uses `chpasswd` on the remote host to change the passwords.

The password-changing code is simpler because of `chpasswd`, but making a backup copy of the old shadow entries is a little more complicated because we're using `getent shadow` on the remote host too.

```
join -t : -j 1 -o 2.{1..2} \
    <(getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 1000 {print $1}' | sort) \
    <(getent shadow | sort) | 
  ssh remotehost 'umask 0027 &&
    getent shadow > /etc/shadow.old &&
    chgrp shadow /etc/shadow.old &&
    chpasswd -e 2>/dev/null'
```

It pipes only the first two fields, the username and the encrypted password (output format is one "username:password" pair per line), into ssh.  After making a backup copy of the old shadow file, the remote shell runs `chpasswd` to change the passwords as specified on stdin.

The `-e` option tells `chpasswd` that the passwords are already encrypted.  Without that option, it would re-encrypt the supplied passwords.

`chpasswd` will complain on stderr about any usernames that don't exist on the remote system, but will still change the passwords for usernames that do exist.  `chpasswd`'s stderr can be redirected to /dev/null as i've shown above.

NOTE: It would be better to pipe stderr into a script that drops only the expected & harmless "username doesn't exist" errors while still displaying other errors.  On my testing VM, the errors output by `chpasswd` for non-existent users look like this:

```
# printf '%s\n' "foo:bar" "xyzzy:fool" | chpasswd
chpasswd: (user foo) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 1, user foo) password not changed
chpasswd: (user xyzzy) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 2, user xyzzy) password not changed
```

Comment: Join your input to `chpasswd` with the first column from `getent passwd` to remove the "user not found" issue.

Comment: yes, that would work. or exclude UIDs <= 1000 again.  something like `join -t : -j 1 -o 2.{1..2} <(getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 1000 {print $1}' | sort) - | chpasswd -e` as the last line.